# AWK command does not work, why. Trying to compair columns of different files and then get an output into another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

Hi I am trying to output the columns $5 and $6 (file2) where: the column $5 (file1) and $3 (file2) are similar and $3 (file1) and $2 (file2)are similar.

This is my code:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$3,$5] = 1; next } $2 in a && $3 in a {print $5, $6 > "test.tbd" }' file_1 file_2
```

unfortunately nothing happens if I run it. Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Can you please add sample input and expected output? (remove file redirection for the debug)

Answer (score 4):

You used the pair `$3,$5` as the index for `a[]` when you populated it:

```
a[$3,$5] = 1
```

so use the pair `$2,$3` as the index for `a[]` when accessing it:

```
($2,$3) in a
```

Using `$2 in a && $3 in a` is testing for `$2` and `$3` being 2 separate indices of `a[]`, not the combination `$2,$3` being one index of `a[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It makes sense to me. My code is still not working but I think maybe there is another issue, maybe with the data itself. 
Thanks a lot!